# DataFrame fail to find the column name after join condition

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting one issue like "**sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve column_name**" when performing one join operation using dataframe API. Though the column name exists and same join operation is working fine when tried with SQL format of HiveContext. In the following code base,

```
DataFrame df= df1
  .join(df2, df1.col("MERCHANT").equalTo(df2.col("MERCHANT")))
  .select(df2.col("MERCH_ID"), df1.col("MERCHANT")));
```

I have tried with "alias" function too, but got the same problem "Can't resolve column name." and throwing following exception.

> resolved attribute(s) MERCH_ID#738 missing from MERCHANT#737,MERCHANT#928,MERCH_ID#929,MER_LOC#930 in operator !Project [MERCH_ID#738,MERCHANT#737];
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:38)

Spark Version: 1.6

The problem has been faced in both Scala and Java Spark.

In Scala, the issue got resolved using '**alias**', but in Java, I am still getting the error.

Comment: Can you show the schemas of `df1` and `df2`? Your code works for me when they contain the necessary columns; By the error message, it seems like `df2` contains a column named `MERCH_ID` and not a column named `MERCHANT_ID`, and that is the reason for the error.

Comment: Thanks Tzach, for your response. But it was a small typo. The column name is "MERCH_ID" and it is correct & I have updated my post too. As I have mentioned in my post, only DaraFrame API is not working, but working fine when using SQL query of HiveContext, registering 2 temporary table from df1 & df2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my experience it is best to avoid `DataFrame.col` and `DataFrame.apply` unless necessary for disambiguation (aliasing is still better). Please try using independent `Column` objects:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;

DataFrame df= df1.alias("df1").
  .join(df2.alias("df2"), functions.col("df1.MERCHANT").equalTo(functions.col("df2.MERCHANT")))
  .select(functions.col("df2.MERCH_ID"), functions.col("df2.MERCHANT")));
```

Answer (score 1):

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;

Dataset  joinedDF = DF1.join(DF2, DF1.col("_c1").equalTo(DF2.col("_c1")));

here _c1 represents the column 1, if the column does not have a header